# My system is running in low graphics mode and I had forgot my username please help me

Tags: 16.04

I had forgot login user name and It is running in low graphics mode please help me.

Comment: Do you get low graphics mode before or after the login screen? If it's before, try logging in as guest and see if that works.

Comment: Which one do you want help with? Your forgotten username? Or your low-graphics? One question per Question, please.

Comment: Actually it is in low graphics mode and if I want to login the username should be known i had forgot the username and the system is running in low graphics mode in this i can't even see any thing except this login:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easiest solution: a reinstall. If you're not sure about your password try auto login when in the "Who are you?" part of Ubiquity.
If you *really* don't renember your username, try `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`.

To get rid of low graphics mode you need to install your propietary drivers for your GPU. The majority of them can be found in the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Comment: Thanks sir but I know my password but I had forgot the username /login id

Comment: I've updated it so you can fix your double dilemma.